# JW8 Player Hide CC Button

Tags: jwplayer

I have recently updated my JW player to JW8 and after update i am getting CC button only in safari browser and on clicking on CC button i don't see any caption. Basically i would like to remove CC button as none of the video which is played in my application has caption.

I have tried to include the following code in JW setup function renderCaptionsNatively : false. But after adding the same i could still see the CC button.

```
jwplayer("video").setup({                           
                            file: _this18.$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(videoPlayURL),
                            autostart: true,
                            height: "300",
                            width: "100%",
                            playbackRateControls: [0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0],
                            **renderCaptionsNatively: false, //Hide CC button**
                            primary: "html5",
                            hlshtml: true 
                        });
```

Can any one please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to hide cc button.

Include the following CSS style to your code.`.jw-icon-cc{      display:none;   }`